# Using GPU in VS code container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I want to use a GPU inside a Visual Studio Code docker container to train model with TensorFlow. To build an image for my container I use next Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/anaconda:0-3


ARG PROJECT_NAME=fire_rec

ARG NODE_VERSION="none"
RUN if [ "${NODE_VERSION}" != "none" ]; then su vscode -c "umask 0002 && . /usr/local/share/nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION} 2>&1"; fi


COPY environment.yml* .devcontainer/noop.txt /tmp/conda-tmp/
RUN if [ -f "/tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml" ]; then umask 0002 && /opt/conda/bin/conda env update -n base -f /tmp/conda-tmp/environment.yml; fi \
    && rm -rf /tmp/conda-tmp


WORKDIR /srv/${PROJECT_NAME}

COPY requirements.txt /srv/${PROJECT_NAME}

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pip
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

"requirements.txt" consists of:

```
opencv-python
tensorflow-gpu
numpy
matplotlib
albumentations
tensorflow_addons
```

Also I have .devcontainer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Anaconda (Python 3)",
    "build": { 
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "args": {
            "NODE_VERSION": "none"
        }
    },

    "settings": { 
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/conda/bin/python",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/opt/conda/bin/autopep8",
        "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/opt/conda/bin/yapf",
        "python.linting.flake8Path": "/opt/conda/bin/flake8",
        "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/opt/conda/bin/pycodestyle",
        "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/opt/conda/bin/pydocstyle",
        "python.linting.pylintPath": "/opt/conda/bin/pylint"
    },

    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
    ],

    "remoteUser": "vscode",
}
```

I successfully built the image and launched the container. But when I try to launch this code in jupyter-notebook inside the container:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

I get next messages:

```
2022-05-05 14:42:02.712454: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2022-05-05 14:42:02.712483: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:163] no NVIDIA GPU device is present: /dev/nvidia0 does not exist
```

So this code fails to use GPU. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: To use CUDA (GPU) inside a container, its generally recommended that you install [the NVIDIA container toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html).

Answer (score 19):

make sure you have [NVIDIA Container Toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/install-guide.html) installed. then add this to your .devcontainer.json:

```
"runArgs": [
    "--gpus",
    "all"
]
```

check [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_image-or-dockerfile-specific-properties) to see how you can add more options to your .devcontainer.json

Answer (score 2):

Please change your code to your `devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "Anaconda (Python 3)",
    "build": { 
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "args": {
            "NODE_VERSION": "none"
        }
    },

    "settings": { 
        "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/opt/conda/bin/python",
        "python.linting.enabled": true,
        "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
        "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/opt/conda/bin/autopep8",
        "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/opt/conda/bin/yapf",
        "python.linting.flake8Path": "/opt/conda/bin/flake8",
        "python.linting.pycodestylePath": "/opt/conda/bin/pycodestyle",
        "python.linting.pydocstylePath": "/opt/conda/bin/pydocstyle",
        "python.linting.pylintPath": "/opt/conda/bin/pylint"
    },

    "extensions": [
        "ms-python.python",
        "ms-python.vscode-pylance"
    ],
    
    "runArgs": ["--gpus","all"
    ],

    "remoteUser": "vscode",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisite:**

1. The machine has GPU graphics card, and GPU graphics card driver is installed;
2. Installation environment of GPU, CUDA, etc;
3. Open PM attribute in NVIDIA-SMI;
4. GPU equipment specified in the program;

Run the python program in the terminal and use the command: `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python filename.py`

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I tried many options of specifying "gpus" in "runArgs" (through ID, exact name of GPU) and none works. On the other hand when I run container by hand everything works. For me it looks like some bug in vsc :/

Just in case, I made issue on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6989

Comment: note that spaces are not allowed in runargs: `"--gps all"` is not going to work but `"--gpus=all"` or `"--gpus", "all"` should both work